# PHP Gradual calculate

Tags: php, math

I have a problem with gradually calculating a value in PHP.

This is just an example. A user can level up, and when he reaches `level 5` he unlocks the ability to play missions. The difficulty of a new generated mission is defined by a number: from `1` that is an easy mission to `10` that is a very difficult mission. See this table:

```
o   5:   1,   1,   2,   2,   3,   3,   3,   3,   3,   3 and so on
o   6:   1,   2,   2,   2,   3,   3,   3,   3,   3,   3
o   7:   2,   2,   2,   3,   3,   3,   3,   3,   3,   3
o   8:   2,   2,   3,   3,   4,   4,   4,   4,   4,   4
o   9:   2,   3,   3,   4,   4,   4,   4,   4,   4,   4
o   10:  3,   3,   4,   4,   5,   5,   5,   5,   5,   5
o   11:  3,   4,   4,   5,   6,   6,   6,   6,   6,   6
o   12:  4,   4,   5,   6,   7,   7,   7,   7,   7,   7
o   13:  4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8
o   14:  5,   6,   7,   8,   9,   9,   9,   9,   9,   9
o   15:  6,   7,   8,   9,   10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10
o   16:  7,   8,   9,   10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10
o   17:  8,   9,   10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10
o   18:  9,   10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10
o   19:  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10
o   20: same as 19
```

This means: in `level 5` the first mission is *very easy (difficulty 1)*, the second one too, and the third mission is *difficulty 2*. And when the player is `level 18`: the first mission has a difficulty of *9* and the second and following missions have a difficulty of *10*.

But: how to generate the difficulty of the missions?
I have two variables:

```
<?php
$current_player_level
$current_mission_in_level
?>
```

So:

```
<?php
$current_player_level=8;
$current_mission_in_level=3;
//This should return: 3
?>
```

So I need a function that returns the difficulty when the two variables above are provided.

I don't have any code because I don't know how to begin.

Comment: Idoes table exist? in what a form?

Comment: No it's not a table. So I need to calculate it by PHP.

Comment: And what is a rule? If you can't write in php, say in words

Comment: I'm sorry. I edited my question. The last value in each is the highest possible! So in the first one that is 3 and in the last one it is 10.

Comment: why it bedin from 5 level? how count the maximun on intermediate levels, 6,7,8... ?

Comment: You want we we invent this? Or you know but don't say ? :)

Comment: Haha I'm sorry. The first 5 should be generated as you see in my example. The values from 6 and more should be the value of 5. That means that every LAST value you see is the max value for that level.

Comment: Really you have written full table as 2D array. So you can fill the array, take any answer below, and use. Am i wrong?

Comment: You see a sort of gradual increment in the numbers. But the max value is always 10. Hope it is more clear now.

Comment: No that is absolutely a good answer. Was just wondering if it is possible by calculating it in PHP!

Comment: *a sort of gradual increment* OK now i understand your question

Comment: I removed the ellipsis!

Comment: I don't find any regular sequence that can be converted into a formula. From 13 to 19 there is a clear sequence, but, the previous levels are not regular. Maybe you should accept Bing's answer.

Comment: If you're looking for a formula, rather than a fixed table, you'll have to decide on the difficulty you want.  I studied math in college and I don't see any formula which would product the numbers you provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest storing the difficulties in a 2-dimensional array (also called a "matrix" sometimes).  The code would look like so:

```
$matrix_val = array(5 => array(1,   1,   2,   2,   3),
                    6 => array(1,   2,   2,   2,   3),
                    7 => array(2,   2,   2,   3,   3),
                    8 => array(2,   2,   3,   3,   4),
                    9 => array(2,   3,   3,   4,   4),
                    10 => array(3,   3,   4,   4,   5),
                    11 => array(3,   4,   4,   5,   6),
                    12 => array(4,   4,   5,   6,   7),
                    13 => array(4,   5,   6,   7,   8),
                    14 => array(5,   6,   7,   8,   9),
                    15 => array(6,   7,   8,   9,   10),
                    16 => array(7,   8,   9,   10,  10),
                    17 => array(8,   9,   10,  10,  10),
                    18 => array(9,   10,  10,  10,  10),
                    19 => array(10,  10,  10,  10,  10));
```

Then all you have to do is:

```
$difficulty = $matrix_val[$current_player_level][$current_mission_in_level];
```

NOTE: The "current mission in level" assumes 0 is the first index.  So the third mission in level 13 would be referenced as `$matrix_val[13][2]` (notice `[2]`).  If you want to shift this you can either add individual keys to each level, or simply "pad" a meaningless entry at the start of each inner array.  (If this is confusing, let me know and I'll expand.)

For reference, check out the [official Array PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), then you might want to [read up on 2-dimensional arrays](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp), too.

Answer (score 1):

You should use arrays.

You can use 2D array (like a table) to store your levels and difficulties, and then get the right value according to the position you want.

For example:

```
$table = array(
    5 => array(1, 1, 2, 2, 3),
    6 => array(1, 2, 2, 3, 3),
    7 => array(2, 2, 3, 3, 4)
);
```

I'm not showing the all array here.

So if you want to know for example the difficuly, you can use:

```
$current_difficulty = $table[$current_player_level][$current_mission_in_level];
```

The is no much math here, just knowing [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Answer (score 1):

```
// Filling 2D array with linear gradient from left top to right bottom
// There are some math for this. But i'm not sure it is needed

$MIN = 5.0;  // min difficalty
$MAX = 9.0;  // max difficalty
$M = 15.0;   // Level legnth - 1
$N = 7.0;    // Levels count -1

$res = array();
for($y = 0; $y <= $N; $y++) 
   for($x = 0; $x <= $M; $x++) 
     {
      $y1 = ($N*$y-$M*$x+$M*$M)*$N/($M*$M+$N*$N);
      $res[$N-$y][$x] = round($MAX - $y1/$N*($MAX-$MIN));

   }
for($i=0; $i <= $N; $i++) {
   $line = $res[$i];
   echo implode(' ', $line)."\n";
   }
```

Output:

```
5 5 5 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 8 8 8 8
5 5 6 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 8 8 8 8 8
5 5 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 8 8 8 8 8
5 6 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 8 8 8 8 9
5 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 8 8 8 8 8 9
6 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 8 8 8 8 9 9
6 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 8 8 8 8 8 9 9
6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 8 8 8 8 9 9 9
```